# How to not have multiple stages open while displaying multiple scenes/nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I have a draggable button class that displays a button to my screen which can be moved around with a mouse drag. However each draggable button is in a separate stage->scene->pane->node in order to show each individually.
[image]

is there a way to add multiple draggable buttons to my screen without having a millions stages open?

I thought maybe having one transparent stage the size of the screen?
But i don't see how that would work if I can only show one scene at a time.

```
//Draggable button class

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DraggableButton extends Button{
    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;

    public DraggableButton(Stage stage){
        this.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            xOffset = event.getSceneX();
            yOffset = event.getSceneY();
        });
        this.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
//Draggable button object

import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class ButtonDragV2 {
    private ButtonCollection btnCollection = ButtonCollection.getInstance();
    private Stage stage;
    private DraggableButton btn;
    private VBox root;
    private Scene scene;
    private ButtonStacker bs;

    public ButtonDragV2(){
        stage = new Stage();
        btn = new DraggableButton(stage);
        root = new VBox();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        bs = new ButtonStacker();

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        root.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        btn.setPrefSize(100,100);
        VBox.setVgrow(btn, Priority.ALWAYS);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        ...

        stage.show();
        btnCollection.addButton(this);
    {
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Fro each dialog you create if you set the:

```
stage.initOwner(mainStage);
```

to the same initOwner there will only be one icon

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are instantiating a new stage, node, scene, etc. each time you create a new ButtonDragV2. What you want to do is instead inject he dependencies in the constructor like so:

```
public class ButtonDragV2 {

    ...

    private Stage stage;
    private VBox root;
    private Scene scene;

    public ButtonDragV2(State stage, VBox root, Scene scene, ...){
        this.stage = stage;
        this.root = root;
        this.scene = scene;

        ...

    }
}
```

Note that the `...` are not correct syntax, I'm simply putting these here to show that you could potentially inject more dependencies if possible (can't say for sure what they should be since I'm not familiar with javafx).

Finally, in my opinion you should just inject the root in the constructor and add your button to it, I don't see a reason why you are injecting your scene and stage since you don't seem to be interacting with them at all. You also shouldn't be calling `stage.show()` from your button class since it's not really appropriate to do so from here.

PS: you should probably look at a couple of Object Oriented programming tutorials to wrap your head around how it works and how to better implement it in your code :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can show multiple `Button`s in the same `Scene`.

**Example**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setBackground(null);
    Node[] btns = new Node[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i] = new Button("Button "+(i+1));
    }
    btns[0].relocate(10, 10);
    btns[1].relocate(400, 10);
    btns[2].relocate(200, 200);
    btns[3].relocate(10, 400);
    btns[4].relocate(400, 400);

    root.getChildren().addAll(btns);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.setFill(null);

    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```